# Transcendence on $ \alpha+f(\alpha), \alpha f(\alpha) $ and $ \alpha/f(\alpha) $ where $ \alpha$ is transcendental

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

Let $f(x)$ be a real transcendental function with algebraic coefficients. So  $f(x)$ and $x$ are algebraically independent. Let $\alpha$ be a transcendental number, are the numbers $$\alpha+f(\alpha),\ \alpha f(\alpha),\  \alpha/f(\alpha)$$ transcendental?
It is clear these numbers are transcendental if $f(\alpha)$ is algebraic, but what if $f(\alpha)$ is transcendental? It seems in this case these numbers are also transcendental because $f(x)$ and $x$ are algebraically independent, but I'm not able to show this. I'm sorry maybe the description above is not satisfactoty. Here is a specific version: If $\alpha$ is transcendental, then are $$\alpha+\cos(\alpha), \ \alpha\cos(\alpha),\ \alpha/\cos(\alpha)\\ \alpha+e^{\alpha},\ \alpha e^{\alpha},\ \alpha/e^{\alpha}$$  transcendental?

Comment: Dear 好きな人がいません: Your question keeps changing from version $n$ to version $n+1$ whenever you get a negative answer to version $n$. I start fearing that the process will never converge (let alone that doing something like this is considered, I think, unfair here on MathOverflow). If you have a new question, it could make more sense to post it on a new thread (after giving it enough of a thought). With that said, I don't understand what you're asking for in the current version of the OP: Isn't $\cos(\cdot)$ a transcendental function?

Comment: You write that $f$ being "a real transcendental function with algebraic coefficients" means, for example, that "if $f(x)$ involves $\sin$ and $\cos$, then $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $\sin x$, $\cos x$ and $x$ with nonzero algebraic coefficients". But this is not the standard definition of a real transcendental function (and, to be honest, makes little sense whatsoever): Isn't the function $f: \mathbf R \to \mathbf R \colon x \mapsto \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) + x$ a "polynomial in $\sin x$, $\cos x$ and $x$"?

Comment: I'm sorry, that sentence is not a precise description. What I want to ask is something like this: if $\alpha$ is transcendental, then are $\alpha+\cos(\alpha)$, $\alpha\cos(\alpha)$ and $\alpha/\cos(\alpha)$  transcendental?

Comment: Really, why don't you start a new thread? This is a totally different question that the original one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two counterexamples to the specific question at the end.

1. Let $\alpha$ be the unique real solution to $xe^x=1$. This number is also called the [omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant#Transcendence). It is transcendental by the Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem which (in particular) says that if $x$ is nonzero and algebraic then $e^x$ is not algebraic. So if $\alpha$ were algebraic then LW would imply that $e^\alpha=1/\alpha$ is not algebraic, a contradiction.
2. Let $\alpha$ be the unique real solution to $x=\cos(x)$. This number is also called the [Dottie number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number). It is transcendental, again by the Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem. Indeed, suppose $\alpha$ is algebraic. Then so is $i\alpha$, and so $e^{i\alpha}$ is not algebraic by LW. But $e^{i\alpha}=\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)=\alpha+i\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Last time I checked, the entire function $f \colon \mathbf C \to \mathbf C \colon z \mapsto  a\exp(iz)$ was transcendental for every non-zero $a \in \mathbf C$. So, taking $\alpha = -a = 2\pi$ yields a negative answer for the "$\alpha + f(\alpha)$" case; and taking $\alpha = a^{-1} = 2\pi$ yields a negative answer for the "$\alpha f(\alpha)$" case. The "$\alpha - f(\alpha)$" and "$\alpha/f(\alpha)$" cases are trivial variants of the "$\alpha + f(\alpha)$" and "$\alpha f(\alpha)$" cases, resp.

**Edit.** To address the question in the first comment under this answer, the function $f \colon \mathbf R \to \mathbf R \colon x \mapsto a \cos x$ is transcendental for every non-zero $a \in \bf R$, with $f(2\pi) = a$. So again, taking $\alpha = -a = 2\pi$ yields a negative answer for the "$\alpha + f(\alpha)$" case; and taking $\alpha = a^{-1} = 2\pi$ yields a negative answer for the "$\alpha f(\alpha)$" case.

Comment: @Tringali, thanks so much! I edit the question for real $f(x)$ because I realize I'm dealing with real functions. So how do you think the real case? Or is there any reference on this?

Comment: I think this is not a question particularly suited to MathOverflow. In any case, there you have your answer. Also, I don't think it was a good idea to add in the "α−f(α)" case: It sheds a bad light on the OP, as it's a trivial variant of the "α+f(α)" case.

Comment: Ok, Tringali, after your helpful examples I now clarify the statement of the question. Please forgive my fault.